# TinyMCE multiline save

Tags: asp.net, tinymce, multiline

I use TinyMCE. I must have the information entered in the textarea(TinyMCE), stored in a database. By clicking the button I get the text textarea, save text in DB.
However, the database does not get `<р>`-tags what causes it? How to solve it?

TextBox:

```
<asp:TextBox CssClass="test" ID="tbComment" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

How I get and save text:

```
db.Comment.InsertOnSubmit(new Comment() { Author = tbAuthor.Text, Comment_text = tbComment.Text, News_id = int.Parse(Session["changeNews"].ToString()), PostDate = DateTime.Now });
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: you know that the tinymce editor is not equal the textarea?

Comment: a contenteditable iframe, the textarea (html source element) becomes hidden. when the editor gets shut down the content gets written into that textarea